# Nothing appear in my joomla website except home page

Tags: joomla

I am new to using Joomla! I have installed my template but when I try to create about us or contact us page the content of these pages does not appear, Although i made an article and linked it to a module.

I installed joomla in my localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a module to show, you need to ensure the following:

1. The configured position must be a valid position for the active template
2. The status in the module must be set to Published
3. The current date must meet in the Start Publishing - Finish Publishing interval (you can leave these empty, of course)
4. The page assignment (second tab) must be set correctly

In case a module doesn't show up at one of my sites, it is most often because of the page assignment being incorrectly configured (4).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some menu items which link to your articles.

Depending on the template, you may need to install a menu extension. For example, Gantry 4 templates need RokNavMenu.

Comment: I've already done this but the pages are blank and do not show any content.

Comment: What do you mean by *I have installed my template* ? Does the pb appears with protostar ?